# Direction of tick marks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plot

Is there a way to make the direction of the tick marks on the bottom of the xaxis point outward, but the top ones point inward, using matplotlib?

Answer (score 4):

Yes! You can use the set_tick_params() method to do this. Here's an example for setting up a histogram to work as you described:

```
hist.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')  # Adding ticks to both top and bottom
hist.xaxis.set_tick_params(direction='in', which='top')  # The bottom will maintain the default of 'out'
```

Comment: the second line seems to no longer work: `ValueError: 'top' is not a valid value for which; supported values are 'major', 'minor', 'both'`

Comment: Also, is there a way to set this behavior by default via `rcParams`?

Answer (score -3):

You can change the ascending/descending order of tick marks by passing in limits for the x and y-axes that decrease.

I.E. to make the x-axis go from 10 to 0, instead of 0 to 10 and the y-axis to go from 10 to -10, you can do:

```
plt.xlim(10, 0)
plt.ylim(10, -10)
```

Here is an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/invert_axes.html) from matplotlib demonstrating this functionality on a simple case.

Comment: This has to do with the labels on the tick marks. I am asking about the tick mark lines on the graph, and whether they point in towards the graph or outwards.